# Extracting probability from density object

Tags: r

I am currently building density objects for an ecology project I am working on.  The `density` function in `R` works quite nicely for fitting density functions to my data.

An example of how I am using the `density` function is shown below:

```
dens.iris <- density(iris$Sepal.Length, bw = "bcv")
```

This works very well.  However, the `predict` function does not seem to work with `density` objects.  Does anyone know a way to extract the density value for a specific point (e.g. in the `iris` dataset, extract a Sepal.Length of 6.432)?  It is important that I use a `biased cross validation` technique for this.

Comment: Have a look at the `str()` function to explore objects in R. From your example I can see that `dens` objects are just lists of 7 vectors. `dens.iris$y` will get you the y values of density for each value of `dens.iris$x`. I'm not sure you really need to use R's predict function - it would be easy to implement on your own since a "predict" function would just linearly interpolate an input value between values of `dens.iris$x` and `dens.iris$y`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `approxfun` function to linearly interpolate points between those given by the density result. Thus you could use

```
diris <- with(dens.iris, approxfun(x, y, rule=1))
diris(6.432)
# [1] 0.349344
```

also

```
curve(diris(x), from=4.0, to=7.9)
```

[image]

Of course you have to remember that values of a density curve are not the same thing as probabilities. As with any continuous distribution, the probability that the sepal length is exactly 6.432 is 0.

Comment: Great answer as always @MrFlick  Good note about the probability being zero as well.  Thanks!